# Pythonic dict with values as list()

Tags: python

Answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070602/python-tuple-problems), in which to identify similar results of a function `func` applied to a `collection` of argument items, I created a dictionary (`resultsdict`) in which keys were the results and values were lists of the matching argument items. The code looked like:

```
resultsdict = {}
for item in collection: 
    result = func(item)
    if result in resultdict.keys():
        resultdict[result].append(item)
    else:
        resultdict[result] = [item]
```

It did the job. Fine.

**But is there a better way ?**

The reason I ask is that I came across two similar pieces of code in the last 24 hours.

Note: The last 4 lines (`if ... else ...`) can be replaced by a oneliner:
`resultdict[result] = resultdict[result] + [item] if result in resultdict.keys() else [item]`
but that seems to induce copy of the list.

Comment: look at `.setdefault` dict method or `.defaultdict` data type from the `collections` library

Comment: `for item in collection: resultsdict.setdefault(func(item), []).append(item)`…

Comment: `resultdict[result] + [item] if result in resultdict.keys() else [item]` would be highly inefficient. Don't try to make everything one-liners. The `if-else` statement version is much better than the conditional expression one-liner from an efficiency perspective *and* a readability perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
resultsdict = {}
for item in collection: 
    result = func(item)
    resultdict.setdefault(result, []).append(item)
```

Alternatively you may consider using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

resultdict = defaultdict(list)
for item in collection: 
    result = func(item)
    resultdict[result].append(item)
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) say that defaultdict is "simpler and faster" than using setdefault for this use case. (I don't know if this is backed up by performance data, though, and if your collection is small it probably doesn't matter either way.)

Comment: Both have pros and cons. In general I avoid returning defaultdict as the consumer may inadvertently modify the collection